# after install of 15.10 - no desktop just wall paper

Tags: unity, system-installation

Machine HP Pavilion dv5z-1200 Processor: AMD Turion X2 Dual Core RM-74 (which I believe is 64 bit) 3Gig Memory.
Yesterday I flashed the BIOS to the latest as per HP.

I tried to install release 15.10-desktop-amd64, because I believe this is a 64 bit chip. Did not work, burned the image to USB stick booted the machine ran the install. No errors during install. Then re-booted the machine, just got a blank screen..
Next release I tried was 15.10-desktop-i386. Burned the image to USB stick, ran the install, the install seems to have gone well. Rebooted , logged in and then the machine processed a load of updates. After the updates the machine required a re-boot. After the re-boot logged-in , but no Desktop. Just a background/wallpaper.
Poked around for posting related to this issue and found this:  [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).  Follow the instructions and was able to run ccsm  and was able to select/turn-on Ubuntu Unity plugin.   But no change even after a re-boot.

What I need to get out of this exercise is a basic machine with PostgeSQL running, connected to my LAN and the internet.  Web browser , Text editor and other basic development tools.

Your kind assistance is requested

KD

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the ISO you downloaded was corrupted. Did you verify the checksum?

Also, are you using 15.10 for any specific reason? It is the bleeding-edge. I recommend using 14.0.4 as it is the most stable.

Comment: I had tried 15.04 and got had the same issue.  See here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/745309/after-install-of-15-04-no-desktop  Issue was closed because that release is no longer support,  therefore I went to 15.10

Comment: I mentioned 14.0.4(The LTS version), not 15.0.4 :)

Comment: OK that is an interesting suggestion.   Any opinion on 64 bit vs 32 bit.

Comment: If you have >= 2GB RAM and you have a 64-bit CPU, go for the 64-bit version

Comment: 64-bit version does not run on this machine.  tosses error on re-boot after install.  Installed ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386  this installed and will boot.  however original issue continues, no desktop just wallpaper.  tried the following as per above   started a tty2 session Cntrl-Alt-F2 , logged in and then entered dconf reset -f /org/compiz as above. got error:: cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

It should fix your issue.
Compiz is a compositing window manager that uses 3D graphics hardware to enhance the usability and aesthetics of the desktop environment.

Comment: I want to the release ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386  started a tty2 session Cntrl-Alt-F2 , logged in and then entered dconf reset -f /org/compiz as above.  got error:: cannot autolaunch  D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Comment: oh checked the checksum  all is good

Comment: should I start a new thread the subject is now misleading?

Comment: @KBD. The command that i gave you can only be run from the XSession. Just do 'Ctrl+Alt+T' using your keyboard and you will get a terminal to enter these commands.

Comment: I am sitting at a window that is asking for my password, when I type in my password it "goes away" for 2 seconds and then returns to the same logon screen.  entering  'Ctrl+Alt+T'  does not bring up a terminal window..  No progress. thanks for your assistance.

Comment: is there a way to get to an XSession?

Comment: Initially you said you are seeing a blank purple wall paper, right? So what all you have done that has led to login loop issue now?

Comment: a logon dialog on top of a purple wall paper.  I can type in my password, the system goes away for 2 seconds and then return to the same logon screen.  there are some icons in the upper right for language, power and sound.  And shut down  that is all